# In ng2-bootstrap, how do I place the modal backdrop in a specific location?

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-bootstrap

I'm using the modals from ng2-bootstrap. Works great, but it seems to place the backdrop where it wants. I want to place it in a specific location to make sure if covers my fixed position navigation, which it is not doing. In the documentation it gives the name of the selector `bs-modal-backdrop`, but it doesn't say anything about how to use it with a modal.